# Typescript: Require type to be set, if another optional type is set

Tags: typescript

**I want to require a second type, if a first type (which is optional by itself) is set.**
Sometimes I have the problem in code, that with one optional property being set, other properties also need to be given for a react component to work.

Example

```
interface ComponentProps {
    title: string;
    isEnlarged?: boolean;
    text?: string; // <-- If isEnlarged is set, text shouldn't be optional
    imageUri?: string // <--- If isEnlarged is set, imageUri shouldn't be optional
}
```

The reason is to enforce consistent component behaviour through type checks. All enlarged components should have both a text and an image.

Is there a way to achieve that by TypeScript helper functions or logic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a discriminated union:

```
type ComponentProps = {
  title: string;
} & ({
    isEnlarged: true; // asuming this must be true for otehrs to be required
    text: string;
    imageUri: string
} | {
    isEnlarged?: false; // asuming this must be true for otehrs to be required
    text?: string;
    imageUri?: string
})

let a: ComponentProps = { title: "test" } //ok
let b: ComponentProps = { title: "test", isEnlarged: true } //err
let c: ComponentProps = { title: "test", isEnlarged: true, imageUri: "", text: "" } //ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=89&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzHAdhFwAKAnOYDOUAvFAN4BQUUwAlsADYQBcU+w2NKA5gNzkC+UAGRQAFBSpUa+AKIp6AQ2xcIAExbsArhB5QA9HqgL8mhJy7UAFtKgJNbKACNoW6ADM42KHGARL2QmA4J2hsCABHTRow1UpJXwAPYBY2Dm4+SSgaBAUVAFUOFPZzASgAHzI4qVl5JRVVAH4WNwV6fB19Q2NTcysbOwdnamxtKA8vHz8A6mChsMjotSrqCCSm1mL05ezciAKaddSS-gBKcnJGYCMWeCRUdCxcAmIyajpGFgAiXzZPqEEDHAANYXCBXRw3RDINAYHB4QgkUhvBjMKDfCC-AA0WRqimUag0I2gAL0EGw2FBVwAxpC7jDHvCXkjaCivj9gJ9sdI5Hj6oTtFycvlCmjOSskl8-iTgUA)

Comment: Is there a way to achieve that by using conditional types https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html ?

Your solution works, but it introduces duplicate code.

Comment: @Sirhennihau conditional types can switch between two types, that can't change attributs of a type, you would still need to define the two versions that are present in the union. You could use `Partial` and generics something like : `type X<T>={
    isEnlarged: T
    text: string;
    imageUri: string
} type ComponentProps = {
  title: string;
} & (X<true> | Partial<X<false>>) ` but unless there are a lot of props,  I doubt it's worth it.